# PHP Ratchet web socket send message workflow

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, ratchet

I'm developing a chat server by PHP Ratchet library and I have a doubt about sending message:

I have the two methods: `onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)` and `onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)`.

When a client connects to chat onOpen method is called and I would to send a response message, for this reason I do `$conn->send($data)`.

if there is an error `onError` is called, but if there isn't error How do I know if everything has been successful since the flow continues anyway? (I do not have a success method).

I ask you the following question because I have to manage the following situation:
when I send the message to a client, if the "send" method goes wrong I have to save on a database the message that I could not send and try to postpone it later, while if the sending was successful I do not have to save anything. My problem is that if the "send" method goes wrong, the "onError" method is called and I only have the instance about the "ConnectionInterface" but not the message I could not send, so at that point how could I? do to recover it?

I hope I was clear in explaining the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, some like this...

@example:

```
// ...

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $connection)
{
    // ...

    $package = [
        'data'  => $data = [] // for example
    ];

    $json = json_encode($package, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    $connection->currentMessage = $json;
    $connection->send($json);

    // $connection->send(null); // uncomment if you wanna simulate error (call onError())
}

// ...

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function onError(ConnectionInterface $connection, \Exception $e)
{
    $connection->currentMessage; <-- your current message

    // ... save message, etc, ...whatever you want :)

    $connection->close();
}
```

Have Fun!